# JSF2.2.1 + form binding + ViewScoped trouble

Tags: jsf-2, binding, mojarra, jsf-2.2, view-scope

I've the following JSF page to try either standard JSF2.2.1 and Primefaces4 CommandLink:

```xhtml
<h:form id="test3" binding="#{test3.hf}">
    <h:commandLink value="Test3" action="#{test3.print('PROVA.....')}" />
    <br />
    <p:commandLink value="PFtest" action="#{test3.print('PROVA.....')}" />
</h:form>
```

... and the relative ***ViewScoped*** managed bean:

```java
@ManagedBean(name="test3")
@ViewScoped
public class Test3 implements Serializable {
    HtmlForm hf;    

    public Test3() {
        super();
    }

    public HtmlForm getHf() {
        return hf;
    }
    public void setHf(HtmlForm hf) {
        this.hf = hf;
    }

    public String print(String text) {
        System.out.println(text + " " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println(hf.getChildren().size());
        return null;
    }

}
```

The strange behavior is that, clicking on one of two CommandLink, **the print method is called two times** !!!
The problem don't occurs if I avoid the form binding or I add an additional binding to CommandLink components.

What do you think about ?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have two commandLinks with the same action?

Comment: This is a simple test case to try either standard Mojarra component and Primefaces component (... but the behavior is the same ...). The "print" method is used only to debug the actions.

Comment: That's an interesting issue. Happening also for me with Mojarra 2.1.26. However, changing bean scope to `@RequestScoped` brings the desired behaviour...

Comment: Yes, `@RequestScoped` works fine, .... but I need `@ViewScoped` :-)

Comment: Seems to be a bug. For some reason, [`UIViewRoot#queueEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#queueEvent%28javax.faces.event.FacesEvent%29) gets called twice, so two events are queued to be performed and the method is consequently being recalled. Would be good to know if it happens with MyFaces also...

Comment: Now I can add an extra contribute: I've just tested same cases using MyFaces 2.2 and it works fine ! (no double invoke). I definitively think that it's a Mojarra BUG :-(

Comment: Would you mind tracking it as a new issue? Haven't found anything similar by myself... Note that it also happens with 2.1.x branch. https://java.net/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Mojarra 2.2.5.
Thanks for contributes.